# Logstash - Saving Soap/Rest Request

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am very new to Elasticsearch and Logstash so I need guidance.

1) We are having different environment e.g dev1, dev2, test, For each environment there is log4j log file which contains SOAP/REST request.

2) I am able to parse those file using GROK pattern and able to save in ES.

3) Our SOAP/REST and request/response is having one of the field called `transactionId`

Sample message:

```
<n:transactionId>f6095126-5397-4f60-8669-c17ff0486c74</n:transactionId>
remaining another 40 elements. ...
```

My search query should be "environment=? and transactionId=?"

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: You want to know what your elasticsearch query should look like, or what your logstash grok pattern should look like?

Comment: I got the grok pattern but want to know how can I add column transactionId  index as it is part of Message attribues.

Comment: e.g GET /megacorp/employee/_search?q=transactionId:f6095126-5397-4f60-8669-c17ff0486c74

Comment: @Rakesh sorry i don't get your question. is your grok pattern already extracting transactionId? If yes are you looking for the query syntax in kibana?

Comment: sorry for late reply. Here is the solution I got it... Thanks for your help..https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-saving-soap-rest-request/36912